# How to check the type of a variable defined by python dataclass directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

If I create and specify a type directly as follows,

```py
INT64 = int
BIGINT = int
VARCHAR256 = str
VARCHAR512 = str

@dataclass
class TempClass(object):
    v1: INT64
    v2: BIGINT
    v3: VARCHAR256
    v4: VARCHAR512
```

When checking the type of a dataclass variable, is there a way to check whether it is a directly specified type?

As a simple example, if you check the type as shown below, it would be nice to be able to output the specified INT64, BIGINT, VARCHAR256, or VARCHAR512 or check the type!

```py
for _i in TempClass.__dataclass_fields__:
    print(type(_i))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "directly specified type"? It doesn't sound like this dataclass is the best way of representing what you want to represent.

Comment: Also, `__dataclass_fields__` is an undocumented implementation detail. If you want to access the fields of a dataclass, use `dataclasses.fields`.

Comment: Those aren't types!

Comment: @blhsing: If you want an alias, `typing.NewType` doesn't do that. Static type checkers treat `typing.NewType` as creating actual new types, not aliases.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference (today, anyway), but I would recommend using `typing.TypeAlias` to make your definitions explicit: `INT64: TypeAlias = int`.

Comment: as a side note, you may wnat to check `ctypes.Structure` instead of dataclass for this kind of class, instead of dataclasses: it will acommodate your data into a "real" bytes structure, and perform  bound checking for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the [`fields()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) of a dataclass in order to retrieve each field's `name` and `type`, as shown below.

However, note that doing so will only print the resolved **type** of each field, i.e. the type to the right of the equals `=` sign below.

For instance, it will resolve the type of the first field -- `v1` -- to `int`, which is likely not what you intend or want.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

INT64 = int
BIGINT = int
VARCHAR256 = str
VARCHAR512 = str

@dataclass
class TempClass(object):
    v1: INT64
    v2: BIGINT
    v3: VARCHAR256
    v4: VARCHAR512


for field in fields(TempClass):
    print(field.name, '-', field.type)
```

Prints:

```
v1 - <class 'int'>
v2 - <class 'int'>
v3 - <class 'str'>
v4 - <class 'str'>
```

---

To work around this, you can add the following to the top of your module:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

This will convert all annotations in the module to a `str` value, so that the annotations are lazy-evaluated.

This is useful in our case, so we know the actual name of the annotation passed in, rather than the resolved or evaluated type (`int` for example).

Example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from sys import modules

INT64 = int
BIGINT = int
VARCHAR256 = str
VARCHAR512 = str


@dataclass
class TempClass(object):
    v1: INT64
    v2: BIGINT
    v3: VARCHAR256
    v4: VARCHAR512


# retrieve globals of the class's module
cls_globals = modules[TempClass.__module__].__dict__

# iterate over each dataclass field, retrieve its name and type
for field in fields(TempClass):
    f_name = field.name
    # field's annotation -- will be a "lazy-evaluated" string value
    f_ann = field.type
    # field's resolved type (for example `str` or `int`)
    f_type = cls_globals[f_ann]
    # custom name for the field's type
    f_type_name = 'STRING' if f_type is str else 'NUMBER' if issubclass(f_type,  (int, float)) else 'UNKNOWN'

    print(f_name, '-->')
    print(f'  annotation (str):  {f_ann!r}')
    print(f'  type:              {f_type.__qualname__}')
    print(f'  type_name:         {f_type_name}')
```

Output:

```py
v1 -->
  annotation (str):  'INT64'
  type:              int
  type_name:         NUMBER
v2 -->
  annotation (str):  'BIGINT'
  type:              int
  type_name:         NUMBER
v3 -->
  annotation (str):  'VARCHAR256'
  type:              str
  type_name:         STRING
v4 -->
  annotation (str):  'VARCHAR512'
  type:              str
  type_name:         STRING
```